# How to determine that the improper integral $\int_{\pi}^{\infty}\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x}dx$ diverges?

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals, divergent-integrals

How is the divergence of the improper integral $\int_{\pi}^{\infty}\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x}dx$ shown and determined with the improper integral comparison test or other methods?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculus $\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{\sin^2x}x\mathrm dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1411385/calculus-int-0-infty-frac-sin2xx-mathrm-dx)

Answer (score 3):

We know that $|\sin(x)| \geq \frac12$ for $x \in [2\pi n + \pi/6, 2\pi n + 5\pi/6]$ (this holds for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$; to see why it's true just visualize the unit circle).  Therefore we can estimate
$$
\int_\pi^\infty \frac{\sin^2x}{x} \,dx \geq \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \int_{2\pi n + \pi/6}^{2 \pi n + 5\pi/6} \frac{\sin^2x}{x} \,dx \geq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1/4}{2\pi n + 5\pi/6},
$$
and this sum can be seen to diverge by comparison with the harmonic series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac1n$.